# How to convert a local variable into global, python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scope

I have created a function that imports a module in python as name you want. I just want to know, how this new local variable can be made accessible in global scope.

```
def myimport(modulename, newname):
    exec('%s = __import__("%s")'%(newname, modulename))

myimport('os', 'pax')
```

now the **pax** variable can't be accessed outside the function, and I want it to be accessible.

Comment: Please do'nt do that.... Python has already syntax for this: `import os as pax`.

Comment: I know there is already a syntax. But maybe in future I may need to do something else and coincide with this same problem. I just want to know how we can do it. :D tq.

Comment: but here you basically violate two things: (a) you use `exec(..)` which is very insecure and a software anti-pattern, and second (b) you aim to create a variable *by name*. What if somebody wants to define this to `'1'`, or `'foo bar'`? Defining it that way will not help (in the end). Most IDEs will also not be able to help with such "dynamic" imports, and it will be very unclear if there is a "name clash".

Comment: Have you considered using importlib ?https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module

Comment: myimport function can be used with try-catch for that. My concern is not about importing a module. I am just wondering if there is any way for an undefined variable name to be shifted from local scope to global.

Comment: @Pax: yes, with `exec('globals()["%s"] = __import__("%s")' % (newname, modulename))`, but again this is horrible. If somebody uses as newname `__spec__"].get(None, globals()).clear() #`, he/she can clear your globals. Do you see what power such function can have? At least `eval` is a tiny bit safer here by writing `globals()[newname] = eval(..)`, but then again, every manager that has an employee that writes such code should instantly fire somebody that does that :)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is just for research purpose, as stated by Willem Van Onsem in the comment section - importing via eval / exec etc. is not considerable in productive code due to the security issues it may raise. The following code works with python 2 and python 3. The trick is to use the global() function to bind the imported module to a global variable:

```
def myimport(modulename):
    module = eval('__import__("%s")' % (modulename))
    globals()[modulename] = module

myimport('os')
print(os.path) # now os can get used ...
```

**Update**

The following code is working without this ugly eval statement:

```
def myImport(modulename):
    globals()[modulename] = __import__(modulename)

myImport("sys")
print(sys.path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the globals dictionary as the second argument to [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec). This will change the code execution scope of exec.

```
def very_bad_idea(name, value):
    exec(f'{name}={repr(value)}', globals())

very_bad_idea('spam', 'eggs')
print(spam)  # prints 'eggs'
```

But please don't do this. Try to find some way that doesn't involve exec.